# Assigning weight to a variable Python/linear equations

Tags: python, algorithm, linear-equation

I am trying to assign a weight to a variable using a minimum value, optimal and maximum.  For example, I have a calculated float for Temperature (Tm) of DNA sequences (calculated based on NN joining algorithm). I am only interested in sequences that fall within a specific temperature range. The opt=61, min=58, max=64. I want to program two linear equations, where the weight of the temperature variable can be used for future comparisons (within the weight variable itself).  For example if Tm = 61, this is most desirable (optimal), thus it should receive a weight of 100.  A Tm of 58 (least desirable) would have a weight of 10, just like Tm of 64 (least desirable) also has a weight of 10.

Pseudocode:

```
def Tm_weight(Tm):
    if Tm == 61:
        weight = 100
    elif Tm > 61:
        weight = ((-30*(Tm)) + 1930)
    else:
        weight = ((30*(Tm)) - 1730)
    return weight
```

This will give me the desired weight, however I'm looking for a much more general way to do this, without actually providing values.  I wish to use argparse (so I can change options (For opt, min and max) from command line, and then still calculate a linear weight for this particular variable. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Looks like the OP wants a formula for which `f(58) = 10`, `f(61) = 100`, and `f(64) = 10`, and all other values are linearly interpolated from those. This isn't really a programming question, and is probably off-topic.

Comment: To the OP: consider `abs(Tm - 61)` -- this is how far you are off from your desired value. Your weight decreases linearly from 100 the more you stray from it, so `weight = 100 - abs(Tm - 61) * k`. Try finding `k` yourself!

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I am looking for a way to maintain the linear relationship, weighting values between 10 and 100, regardless what I enter as min, opt and max.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something more universal like this, however I still don't know if there is a better/more efficient way to do this.
```

```
def Tm_weight(self):
   if self.temp == options.optTm:
      self.temp_weight = 100
   elif self.temp > options.optTm:
      self.slope = (10-100)/(options.maxTm - options.optTm)
      self.inter = (100 - ((10-100)/(options.maxTm - options.optTm))*(options.optTm))
      self.temp_weight = ((self.slope)*(self.temp) + (self.inter))
   else:
      self.slope = (100 - 10)/(options.optTm - options.minTm)
      self.inter = (100 - ((100 - 10)/(options.optTm - options.minTm))*(options.optTm))
      self.temp_weight = ((self.slope)*(self.temp) + (self.inter))
   return self.temp_weight
```